# Framework7 pass data to html

Tags: html-framework-7

I am really new to framework7, and just try to pass app root data to html. This is my app.js.

```
var app = new Framework7({
    root: '#app', // App root element
    id: 'io.framework7.testapp', // App bundle ID
    name: 'Framework7', // App name
    theme: 'auto', // Automatic theme detection

   // App root data
   data: function () {
       return {
         username: 'john' 
     };
  },  
});
```

So how can I pass the data into index.html with js template? 
I have tried the following code, but I got Illegal return statement error...

```
<template>
  <p>Hello, my name is {{name}} </p>
</template>

<script>
  return {
     data: function () {
        return {
          name: this.$root.username,
     };
  }
 };
 </script>
```

I am appreciated if anyone could help me.

Update: 
I have tired

```
{{ $root.userName }}
```

in the index page, it is not working, but it is working in the other pages, is it mean I need replace all content from the index page, then try to use template rending in the index page to access the root data? I really have no idea what I should do with it… Please help…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant pass data to index page directly like other page, you have some tricks you need to do that:

1) its by using/build configuration for initial page route: [Initial Page Route](https://framework7.io/docs/view.html#initial-page-route), In this way you need to try to convert normal index.html to component html by using component template or URL ..etc, Any way in my projects I use second way.

2) Second solution by using Template7 like this:
JS:

```
// init dom script
var MainMenuTemplate         = $$('script#mainMenuScriptTemplate').html();
var compiledMainMenuTemplate = Template7.compile(MainMenuTemplate);
//...inside app or you can create app.on('init') as you like....
on: {
      pageInit: function (page) {
        if(page.name == 'home'){
            var html = compiledMainMenuTemplate({"userName": "Anees"});
            $$('#main-menu-wrapper').html(html);
        }
      },
  },
//..
```

Html:

```
<script id="mainMenuScriptTemplate" type="text/template7">
                <div class="navbar">
                    <div class="navbar-inner">
                            <a href="#" data-panel="panel-left" class="link panel-open icon-only">
                                <i class="icon f7-icons ios-only">menu</i>
                                <i class="icon material-icons md-only">menu</i>
                            </a>
                            <div class="title">{{userName}}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </script>
            <div id="main-menu-wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have solved this issue by setting index with tabs, and the tabs link to other pages, so I could pass the data to the other page, but not index page. I was thinking to use Template7, but I still not really get how I could use it yet, so I used the default app data.

Comment: Welcome mate, By using Template7 you will doing a lot of things, I suppose you learn it and try to write your code with it....its usfall for any hard case or for commn cods, like if you need to concat name with Mrs, Mss...etc you can create helpers...loops...condtions...and control data ...check this url http://idangero.us/template7/#.W-Vl8XV948o and this https://framework7.io/docs/template7.html..... Good luck mate :D

Comment: Thanks to your links. And yes, I already start working on Template7...Well, I guess I am using it. By saying I guess I am using Template7 because I am working on a Framework7 project, I am trying to use condition statement like {{#if}} and looping the data with{{#each}}, it is working, but I am not sure this function is coming from Framework7 or Template7, or by default, Template7 is built in Framework7. Do you know about it?

Comment: Yup, Template7 is build dependence(base) of HBS template, I think its build to be one of freamwork7 component, so that if you learn template7 you will be near to HBS, and you will play perfect with framework7 ^_^

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I am getting there :)